# Can I use Adblock/Adblock Plus to block ads in games that are not in a browser?

Tags: macos, mac, web-browser

Occasionally, there are apps that embed little chunks of the Internet. In most cases, this is a good thing. However, occasionally they are used to display ads.

This is annoying, especially if I've contributed to the development of the software. As a software developer that uses ads to make money, I know that I'd be fine with someone contributing via PayPal and deciding not to view the ads.

This is my situation with quite a few apps: I've contributed to their development and I don't want to be nagged with ads or otherwise. One, in particular, embeds a mini-browser to display ads.

Is there any way I could block such ads using ABP or other OS X software?

Comment: What device do you want to block the internet on?  Mac, PC, iPhone?

Comment: @KatieK: Mac. Oops, should have made that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Adblock/Adblock Plus have to install in a browser. Any app that is not a supported browser [from this list](http://adblockplus.org/en/requirements) is not going to be able to make use of it.

[GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) is one attempt to block all ads for all applications. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I know on my Android tablet I have an adblocker that works for all apps (it uses dns blocking), so there might be something similar for mac.

Comment: +1 for GlimmerBlocker. I've used it for years and it works great. It is a proxy service so it will work with anything that talks to the Internet, not just browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You are going to want to use a `hosts` file to block all ads in all games. First you're going to have to find the domain name of the server that the ads are coming from. You can use a number of programs to monitor network traffic for this step. My favorite is `ettercap-ng`, but you might prefer [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) (if you want to do this on a per-app per-port basis, then Little Snitch will be just right for you without having to modify your `hosts` file). Once you've determined the domain of the ad server you're wishing to block, open up `/etc/hosts` in your favorite terminal text editor with `sudo` permissions (`sudo nano /etc/hosts`) (the file has no extension; it's simply named `hosts`). Add this line to the end of the file after replacing "domain.com" with the domain you're trying to block:

`127.0.0.1 domain.com`

This will tell your Mac to loopback when it comes across "domain.com", thus returning nothing, which essentially gets rid of all ads from that server in every app/program/game on your Mac (keep adding more lines for each ad server, and make them all loopback to `127.0.0.1`). This method will also work on JailBroken devices and Linux.

If you want to use my omnipotent `hosts` file that blocks nearly all ads (it was written primarily for my JailBroken iPod), knock yourself out by replacing yours with mine: http://ss.gy/u Mine works on both desktop computers and mobile devices in multiple countries/languages (primarily the United States and France).

Comment: Yeah, I've edited the HOSTS file before on my PC. Seems like an interesting way to tackle this problem, but a valid way nonetheless.